# $H^n(G,U(1))= H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$ only correct for finite group $G$? Universal coefficient theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Sorry, I'm not studying mathematics. Maybe my question is pretty trivial. When I meet projective representation in physics, I will use the math tools of group cohomology which I'm not familiar with.

I mainly have following two questions:

1. How to prove $H^n(G,U(1))=H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$? Is it only correct for finite group $G$? What's about $G$ is infinite discrete group, like $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$? Is there general way to relate $H^n(G,U(1))$ with infinite discrete group $G$
   to cohomology with coefficient $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Because I only know how to compute group cohomology with coefficient $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_k$.
2. Is $H^n(G,\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\})$ same as $H^n(G,U(1))$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $G$ is a finite group?

Comment: @MikeMiller Is it only correct for finite group? What's about infinite discrete group like $G= \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yeah, when you have $b_1(G) = k$, you'll get a factor of $U(1)^k$ on the LHS but not the RHS. They'll agree after killing off this factor. For 2, $\Bbb C \setminus 0 \cong U(1) \times \Bbb R$, so the LHS is $H^*(G; \Bbb R)$ plus the RHS, and that cohomology group is zero for $G$ finite and sometimes not for $G$ infinite.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks. Is there some general formula to relate $H^n(G,U(1))$ to cohomology with coefficient $\mathbb{Z}$ for $G$ is infinite discrete group?

Comment: There is a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{exp(2\pi i _{-})} U(1) \rightarrow 0$ . If these maps are $G$-equivariant they induce a long exact sequence $\cdots \rightarrow H^{n+1}(G;\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^{n+1}(G;U(1)) \rightarrow H^n(G;\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^n(G;\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \cdots $ .If furthermore $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are trivial $G$-modules (i.e. the $G$-action on them is trivial), then by universal coefficients we have $H^n(G;\mathbb{R}) \cong Hom_\mathbb{Z}(H_n(G;\mathbb{Z}) , \mathbb{R})$.