# Group cohomology of finite groups with real coefficients vanishes?

Tags: finite-groups, exact-sequence, group-cohomology

I tried to understand the answer to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839975/hng-u1-hn1g-mathbbz-only-correct-for-finite-group-g-universa), which is about why $H^n(G,U(1))=H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$. I don't quite understand what the notation "$b_1(G)=k$" means and why we will "get a factor $U(1)^k$". Can someone help me understand this?

Probably it is also related to the fact that $H^n(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ for $n>0$ with trivial group action. Since if it vanishes, then by the long exact sequence
$$...\rightarrow H^n(G,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^n(G,U(1))\rightarrow H^n(G,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^n(G,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow ...$$we can get the desired isomorphism. However, I have no idea how to prove  $H^n(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ with $n>0$ and $G$ a finite group. I tried to use the universal coefficient theorem but in vain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If $|G|=m$ and $n>0$ then $H^n(G,A)$ is $m$-torsion for all $G$-modules $A$,
that is $m H^n(G,A)=0$.
But $\Bbb R$ is divisible, so $mH^n(G,\Bbb R)=H^n(G,m\Bbb R)=H^n(G,\Bbb R)$.
Therefore $H^n(G,\Bbb R)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I Probably in $mH^n(G,\mathbb{R})=H^n(G,m\mathbb{R})$ you are using the functoriality of the group cohomology or $Ext$ functor, right?